# why do I have to include the output of main in a new configuration if the classes in the configuration are in the same package?

Tags: java, gradle

Let's assume a java project with a project structure like so:

```
src
 itest
   java
     SourcesTestsItest.java
 main
   java
       gradle_pr
           pojo.java
 test
    java
        gradle_pr
             SourceSetsTest.java
```

build.gradle

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java Library project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Libraries chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/java_library_plugin.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

sourceSets{
    itest{
         compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        java{
            srcDirs("src/itest")
        }
    }
}

configurations{
    itestImplementation.extendsFrom(testImplementation)
    itestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom(testRruntimeOnly)
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre'
     
    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

     implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.12') 

     itestImplementation('com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre')
}



task printSourceSetInformation(){

    doLast{
        sourceSets.each { srcSet ->
            println "["+srcSet.name+"]"
            print "-->Source directories: "+srcSet.allJava.srcDirs+"\n"
            print "-->Output directories: "+srcSet.output.classesDirs.files+"\n"
            print "-->Compile classpath:\n"
            srcSet.compileClasspath.files.each { 
                print "  "+it.path+"\n"
            }
            println ""
        }
    }
}

task itest(type: Test) {
    description = "Run integration tests"
    group = "verification"
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.itest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.itest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Why do I have use the following lines

```
 compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
```

if the pojo class should be visible in test class under itest as they are in the same package?. How does the default configuration work so test cases can see the generated compiled code of main?

Answer (score 0):

Gradle doesn't know per se how your configurations depend on each other (i.e. it could be that the `main` configuration depends on `itest` or the other way around).

For the `main` and `test` configurations this dependency is established for you when you apply the `java-library` plugin.